# Performance with APC user cache if past 10% memory usage

Tags: php, caching, memcached, apc

I need some type of user cache storage, so currently I'm using APC as both opcode caching and for my user cache that Zend and Kohana can use.  I've heard from several folks that for some reason APC user cache performance degrades if you end up using more than 10% or so of the memory allocated for the user cache.  The general recommendation is to use memcache or memcached for my frameworks user caching.

Does anyone know it the memory usage to performance issue with APC is real or just an urban myth?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so no responses... did some deeper digging and the issue is related to fragmentation of the memory space.  APC does no fragmentation memory management, so unless you have a lot of excess unused memeory, APC will get fragmented and have a hard time finding large enough 'holes' to put new requests to store stuff.

Found some details in various places, but this post gives a better idea: http://xerosphere.net/optimizing-apc-for-drupal